# Vuejs, HTML: re-render or strip the html tags

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3

I am developing a news app with vuejs, but when getting data back, some of its descriptions have HTML tags attached such as `ol`, `li`. I am wondering if:

1. Those tags could be rendered again with HTML.
2. The text stripped with the tags. I've tried using several suggested JavaScript code snippets within the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript), but got `invalid-first-character-of-tag-name`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is part of my code:

```
<template>
  <!-- bootstrap 5 classes -->
  <div class="card mt-3 mx-1" style="width: 18rem; border-radius:10px">
    <!-- image can toggle description -->
    <img
      :src="newsPiece.urlToImage"
      alt="image link lost"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#collapseImage">
    <!-- title -->
    <h5><a :href="newsPiece.url" target="_blank">{{ newsPiece.title }}</a></h5>
    <!-- toggle content from image -->
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseImage">
      <div class="card-body">
        {{ newsPiece.description }}
        <!-- use {{ newsPiece.description.replace(/<script[^>]*>.*<\/script>/gm, '') }} would get error -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    newsPiece: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

picture illustration:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `v-html` directive? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Comment: Million thanks @SimonK. It works.